# TypeError: 'Flatten' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to custom connect layer in the neural network. So, I want to slice layers so I can connect them and later concatenate them together again. I tried to do this with the Flatten layer the following way:

```
inputTensor = keras.layers.Flatten()
group1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :196], output_shape=((32,)))(inputTensor)
group2 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 196:392], output_shape=((32,)))(inputTensor)
group3 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 392:588], output_shape=((32,)))(inputTensor)
group4 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 588:784], output_shape=((32,)))(inputTensor)
group1 = Dense(1)(group1)
group2 = Dense(1)(group2)
group3 = Dense(1)(group3)   
group4 = Dense(1)(group4)
```

But I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Flatten' object is not subscriptable
```

Does this mean that I cannot slice the Flatten layer at all actually and is there any way to convert it to Input layer before slicing it maybe?

Comment: What is the input of the flatten layer? You have probably forgotten to create an `Input` layer and feed it to `Flatten` layer. All models should have at least one `Input` layer. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input).

Comment: The input is the 28x28 image which should be flattened out in 784 values. Also, I manually created the network without the Input layer, only the Flatten: model = Sequential() 
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation=nn.relu))
#model.add(Dense(0, activation=nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(128, activation=nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=nn.softmax))

Comment: This is a different model than the one you are using in your question. With Sequential API you don't need to create an explicit `Input` layer; however, with functional API (i.e. `Model`) you need to explicitly create input layer(s).

Comment: Yes, with the functional API you need to have actual Input layers

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that, I will look it up, thank you very much!
Do you maybe know how I should feed the data to the Input layer so it acts as the Flatten? Should I flatten the data manually using numpy library or is there some better approach?

Comment: I've figured it out, thank you!